# neo4j community V1.9.4 - how to configure IP address and default database location?

Tags: neo4j

Just installed Neo4j community v1.9.4 - thanks for Windows Desktop Launcher. A couple of configuration questions:

1) How can I set the webserver to listen to any connection? In the previous versions I could set the webserver to listen on 0.0.0.0; With the new version, the properties file (neo4j-server.properties) doesn't appear any longer.

2) From the desktop launcher, is it possible to change the default database starting location? I am working with a previously created database and have to point the launcher at it every time I start.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start neo4j-community.exe, a window pops up (neo-4-j Version 2.2.2). 
In the lower left corner, you find a button named *Options...*

Press this button, and you will find the configuration files. 
C:\Users\YOUR_NAME_HERE\AppData\Roaming\Neo4j Community\neo4j-server.properties

When you push "Edit..." you can edit the files you want - in your case the file in the "Server Configuration" section.

Just add

```
# Disable authorization
dbms.security.auth_enabled=false
```

But be aware of the security problems mentioned here http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/security-server.html#security-server-auth

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You should see the installation folder from the Neo4j web console (last tab), in there you can change the `neo4j-server.properies` to your existing database. Same thing goes for the listening.

Comment: Peter - Sorry to be dense, but I am not seeing an installation folder from the Neo4j web console (last tab). The last tab in the web console is "Details Server info"  In addition, a search for "neo4j-server.properties" in the v1.9.4 folder doesn't have any results.

Comment: Peter - the confusion may lay in that I generated my question after using the windows installer vs. the distribution. When I used the installer, the result is a more limited set of folders (no config folder) whereas using the distribution, I get the typical set of folders - including "config."