# Missing conf directory on windows 32 bit neo4j 1.9.4 community edition installation on remote connection

Tags: windows, neo4j

Im trying to follow http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.9.4/server-configuration.html in order to setup the server to accept external connections (org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0 on conf/neo4j-server.properties according to that docs). 
I downloaded the installer from here http://www.neo4j.org/download_thanks?edition=community&release=1.9.4&platform=windows&packaging=exe&architecture=x32. Note that this is an installer not a archive(rar, bz or whatever).
The "conf" directory does not appear. I have been working around (pass vm arguments at the startup etc but im going nowhere). Until now i have found:

- C:\Documents and Settings[myuser]\Datos de
  programa\neo4j-community.vmoptions[file]
- C:\Documents and
      Settings\xp\Datos de programa\Neo4j Community[direcory with a logs
      subdirectory]
- C:\Documents and Settings[myuser]\Mis
      documentos\Neo4j\default.graphdb[directory for default graphdb i
      think, here is a neo4j.properties files, is this the
      neo4j-server.properties files that docs tell me?]
- C:\Archivos de programa\Neo4j Community[directory with
     .install4j,bin,jre(i dont have java installed on system)
     subdirectories]

The bin folder on C:\Archivos de programa\Neo4j Community just contain:
 - neo4j-community.exe
 - neo4j-community.vmoptions
 - neo4j-community-user-vmoptions.loc
 - neo4j-desktop-1.9.4.jar

As you could see there is nothing here like the so mentioned (on docs) Neo4j.bat.
My neo4j server its running perfectly. Even i played a while with the so fun webadmin on localhost:7474. But when i needed to connect from a ubuntu pc and went to docs for help run into the misterious case of missing conf directory.
Are this docs not related to community edition or at least not to the windows 1.9.4 installer?
Right now i just need to connect from a external client, not localhost, but tomorrow i could want to fly in a cow and i suspect for that i will need the conf directory. Any help, in the particular case of remote connection to neo4j server or the general case of missing conf directory will be appreciated.
PS.I found [neo4j community V1.9.4 - how to configure IP address and default database location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015531/neo4j-community-v1-9-4-how-to-configure-ip-address-and-default-database-location) just a few seconds before i finished to write this. Where i could download the distribution and not the installer? In the official site dont seems to be more choices tan 32/64 bit installer???

Comment: I finally went to the linux distribution packet where everything seems to be on his place. Although, based on the format of the url to download de linux distributon i built one to windows. I truly believe that the docs most be updated to take in the precedure for windows new installers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download the distribution, you can download from here
http://www.neo4j.org/download/other_versions 
In community version if you notice, there will be option to download "Installer" or "Binary"
just download the binary package and extract, everything (including conf folder) are inside that.

Btw, If you using the window installer, Neo4J will provide you with user-friendly GUI, if you notice, there will be "Settings.." button there for you to configure your server,
To change the server address for ex, you need to modify neo4j-server.properties
Configuration will be the same, just the location of the config file is different.